# Syncing VirtualEnvs in multiple computer

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I recently purchased a new laptop, so I'd be able to work not just from my workstation.

I have a Django REST app, and for this project I'm using a VirtualEnv.

My question is:
**How can I "sync" the virtualenv to install the new dependencies packages?**

In my workstation I installed Django, Django REST, etc...
What can I do so in my laptop I won't have to manually install the new dependencies every-time?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way. There are many hard-coded directory paths within the virtualenv, so unless you copy the virtualenv to the exact same directory from old machine to the new one, it's hard to get it to work. But on the other side, if you have `requirements.txt` ready, it's almost trivial to install everything from it.

Answer (score 8):

Activate your virtual environment, then run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

However you are transferring the code, you can transfer this file.
Then on your laptop, can you make it part of your sync script:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Typically I have a pair of sh files that looks like

```
# upload change
pip freeze > requirements.txt
git add -a .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

And

```
# Get files
git pull
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into it.

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you use a service like Heroku, this is exactly how they keep your dependencies synced to your code base.

Comment: One could use this answer to add a git hook that automatically updates requirements.txt before each commit.