# How can I use venv with Python 3.10 on two machines

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I work on the same Python projects at home and in the office (both Windows 10).
The local project files and folders on both computers are synchronized with oneDrive. This has been working fine with Visual Studio Code for quite some time. The problem is when I use a Virtual Environment (venv) it doesn't work. I can virtualize a project on one computer, but the environment is not recognized on the other and the Python interpreter from the local directory cannot be selected in the VSC either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Relevant question: [Syncing VirtualEnvs in multiple computer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34210300/12122460). Note that while this is slightly off-topic, it may be a good time to start learning proper version management with git, and also to declaratively specify the dependencies in `requirements.txt`.

Comment: create a virt env on both computer with the same name and the same modules, create a `requirements.txt` file